# With which funding agencies can I register as a reviewer?

Tags: peer-review, funding, research-proposal

I've attended a few workshops on research management and proposal writing, and one thing they've all stressed is the importance of serving as a reviewer for other people's proposals.  Just as peer-reviewing publications can help hone your own paper-writing skills, reviewing proposals is said to give you a better insight into the funding process and thereby help you become a better author of grant applications.  Of course, reviewing proposals might also be rewarding for a host of other reasons (lending one's expertise to a wider scientific community, gaining and sharing knowledge for its own sake, learning to achieve group consensuses with reviewers of different backgrounds/opinions/motivations, establishing professional contacts with other experts and within funding agencies, making some extra income from reviewers' honoraria, etc.).

With that in mind, it seems like it would be a good idea to register one's availability with those funding agencies that issue open calls for a standing pool of reviewers (as opposed to those that seek out and select reviewers entirely *in camera*).  I'm interested in learning with which national and international funding agencies I can do this.

The only one I'm presently aware of, and with which I am already registered, is the European Commission, which has [a standing open call for experts](https://ec.europa.eu/info/jobs-european-commission/experts/become-expert-european-commission_en) to review for Horizon 2020 and many other programs.  Is there a good way of finding other such calls (i.e., other than by identifying all funding agencies and individually checking their websites)?